# As a US passport holder, can I exit the airport during a layover in the Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, us-citizens, fra

I have a lay over in Frankfurt (FRA) Airport for eight hours, and my final destation is Lisbon, Portugal. I hold a US Passport. Will I be able to go outside of FRA Aiport and join a sightseeing tour?

Comment: Henning Makholm gave the best answer, but for the joining an English speaking sightseeing tour part of your question, 8 hours is plenty of time to see the tourist venues in central Frankfurt without a tour guide. With that much time, you might consider catching a train to Ruedesheim.  Richer experience than the Romerplatz.

Answer (score 9):

If you're going to Lisbon, Frankfurt is where you're going to go through the Schengen border controls *anyway*. The flight from Frankfurt to Lisbon is within Schengen and doesn't involve passport checks (except what the airline does at the gate to make sure that the person who flies is the same guy they sold a ticket to).

Once you have arrived at Frankfurt and cleared the border checks you're free to leave the airport.

Comment: +1 for the key part _"you're going to go through the Schengen border controls"_

Answer (score 3):

Citizens of The United States Of America are free to travel throughout a schengen zone for 90 days or less without restriction.

Comment: Wrong. There are restrictions, there is just no need to apply for visa.